# Select a node with XPath whose child node contains a specific inner text

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
    <li><span>abcText1cba</span></li>
    <li><span>abcText2cba</span></li>
</root>
```

I want to select all `li` elements having a `span` child node *containing* an inner text of `Text1` - using an XPath.

I started off with `/root/li[span]` and then tried to further check with: `/root/li[span[contains(text(), 'Text1')]]`

However, this does not return any nodes. I fail to see why, can somebody help me out?

Comment: Your XPath is correct. Which processor are you using, either it does have some serious bug or you might be calling it wrong. As a side note, I think `/li[contains(span, 'Text1')]` Is a bit more elegant and shorter. You certainly con't need the `text()`, just use `.` as it will be automatically converted to an atomic value.

Comment: Your second XPath does appear correct. Perhaps a namespace issue? Is your XML actually in a namespace?

Comment: Just for clarification, because it got a few upvotes over the years: it's been a namespace problem.

Answer (score 29):

Just for readers. The xpath is correct.
OP: Perhaps xpath parser didnt support the expression?

```
/root/li[span[contains(text(), "Text1")]]
```

Answer (score 25):

```
//li[./span[contains(text(),'Text1')]] - have just one target result
//li[./span[contains(text(),'Text')]] - returns two results as target
```

This approach is using something that isn't well documented anywhere and just few understands how it's powerful

[image]

Element specified by Xpath has a child node defined by another xpath

[image]

Comment: what worked for me in my case is
//element1[./childElement[ condition ]]

Comment: This is a bit OT but I really want to thank you for your first screen shot from which I learned that one could do XPath queries in Chrome's JS console!

Answer (score 4):

the xpath [Kent Kostelac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1940851/kent-kostelac) provided:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Text1')]/parent::li
```

could be also be presented as so:

```
//li[span[contains(text(), 'Text1')]]
```

which is a bit shorter and provides improved readability by saying "give me the li that contains the span that displays 'Text1'";
instead of saying "can you see that span that dispalys 'Text1'? ok, so give me its li parent", which is what the original phrasing is actually saying.

Answer (score 4):

To check things in deeply nested children use `.//*` in your Xpath expression.

```
<div class="foo h1">
    <p>
      <span>
         <b>bar</b>
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

To find a div with class `.foo` which also contains a child with text `bar` just use the following xpath expression

```
$x('//div[contains(@class, "foo") and .//*[contains(text(), "bar")]]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath

```
li/*[@innertext='text']
```

Comment: This ignores the span.

Answer (score 1):

Your current xpath should be correct. Here is an alternative but ugly one.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//span/parent::li/span[contains(text(), 'Text1')]/parent::li");
```

We find all the span-tags. Then we find all the li-tags that has a span-tag as child and contains the 'Text1'.

OR simply:

//span[contains(text(), 'Text1')]/parent::li