# How to show information about the selected Engineering Tools using xPath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Good day everyone.

I'm working on a very simple application and I want to implement something that will allow the user to choose a tool from a drop down menu, and after clicking the submit button it will show the information of the chosen tool by extracting the information from the XML File.

I created the dropdown menu by extracting the tool names from the XML file:

```
<form method="POST" action="showspecifictool.php">
<select id="choose" name="choose">
    <?php
        $tools = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');
        foreach($tools as $tool) {
            echo "<option value='test'>".$tool->name."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
```

The next step would be to use XPath to show all the information of the tool chosen from the dropdown menu, however I'm not quite sure how to approach that, and I'd really appreciate the help!

My tools.xml looks something like this:

```
<tool type="learning" web-based="True" free="True">
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <url>...</url>
    <subjects>...</subjects>
    <creators>...</creators>
    <category>...</category>
    <price>...</price>
</tool>
```

Comment: Given what you have, you'd need to construct a valid xpath query to select the tool. Have you tried any of that sort? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48573659

Comment: Though I would advice finding a unique key per tool (e.g. uuid) and use that instead.

Comment: I did, but I unfortunately couldn't get it to work, as it shows an empty output. :(

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://3v4l.org/NL9Wd Though I'm not quite sure how to answer your question, as the whole part of your approach that would select and display the selected tool is missing from your question.

Comment: Well, that's because that's the part I'm struggling at. :) I have a simple dropdown menu that shows the tool names, and after choosing a tool and clicking the submit button, it will redirect to the next page showing all of the information regarding the chosen tool.

Comment: I understand, but what's your question then? How to access the submitted value? How to use it to select from the xml? How to render that selection?

Comment: I would like to access the submitted value (aka the tool name the user chooses from the dropdown menu), and then display the information regarding that tool by extracting it from my xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Xpath expression allow you to fetch nodes from a DOM using location paths and conditions. You need an unique value in the data. An id would work best but lets assume the name is unique.

```
$_REQUEST['tool'] = 'Tool A';

$selectedToolName = str_replace(['"', "'"], '', $_REQUEST['tool'] ?? '');
$tools = new SimpleXMLElement(getXML());
?>
<form method="GET" action="showspecifictool.php">
<select id="choose" name="choose">
    <?php
        foreach($tools as $tool) {
            printf(
                '<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                htmlspecialchars($tool->name),
                $selectedToolName  === $tool->name ? ' selected' : ''
            );
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
<?php

foreach($tools->xpath("(tool[name = '{$selectedToolName}'])[1]") as $tool) {
    var_dump((string)$tool->name);
}
```

Output:

```
<form method="GET" action="showspecifictool.php">
<select id="choose" name="choose">
    <option value="Tool A" selected>Tool A</option></select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
string(6) "Tool A"
```

The Xpath expression fetches the `tool` child elements of the `$tools` context node. `tool[name = 'Tool A']` adds the condition of a specific `name`. `(tool[name = 'Tool A'])[1]` limits the result to the first found node.

In DOM you would need some more Xpath expressions:

```
$_REQUEST['tool'] = 'Tool A';

$selectedToolName = str_replace(['"', "'"], '', $_REQUEST['tool'] ?? '');
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

?>
<form method="GET" action="showspecifictool.php">
<select id="choose" name="choose">
    <?php
        foreach($xpath->evaluate('/*/tool') as $tool) {
            $toolName = $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $tool);
            printf(
                '<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                htmlspecialchars($toolName),
                $selectedToolName  === $toolName ? ' selected' : ''
            );
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
<?php

foreach($xpath->evaluate("(/*/tool[name = '{$selectedToolName}'])[1]") as $tool) {
    var_dump(
        $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $tool)
    );
}
```

Comment: If I want to show all of the information of the chosen tool instead of just the name of it, what do I have to do? Because I want the user to see information of the tool they chose. (all of those information in the tools.xml file I showed above)

Comment: `$tool` contains the found `tool` SimpleXMLElement instance. You can access its properties.

Comment: I unfortunately wasn't able to get your code to work with mine, but thank you for the help anyway. :)

Comment: Also, it is never necessary/beneficial to repeat the option tag's text as its `value` attribute value -- just omit the attribute declaration for cleaner/simpler markup.

Comment: I actually did not remember that 'option' does that. Also, can't remember the last time I used the value as caption. However I think it is more readable to have an explicit value then an implicit.