# Showing information about the selected tool in the dropdown menu

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Good day everyone.

I'm working on a simple application and I want to implement something that will allow the user to choose a tool from a drop down menu, and after clicking the submit button it will show the information of the chosen tool by extracting the information from the XML File.

Here is what my **tools.xml** look like:

```
<tool type="..." web-based="..." free="...">
   <name>Facebook</name>
   <description>...</description>
   <url>...</url>
   <subjects>...</subjects>
   <creators>...</creators>
   <category>...</category>
   <price>...</price>
</tool>
```

This is my **viewspecifictool.php** file where i created the dropdown menu by extracting the tool names from the XML file:

```
       <form method="POST" action="showspecifictool.php" align="center">
        <fieldset>
            <legend align="center">Choose a tool:</legend>

            <select id="choose" name="choose">
                <?php
                    $tools = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');
                    foreach($tools as $tool) {
                        echo "<option value='test'>".$tool->name."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

What I wanna do in **showspecifictool.php** is I want to use XPath to show the information about the tool the user chooses. So let's say, if the user chooses *Facebook* from the dropdown menu, after clicking the submit button I want it to show information about it, and this information will be extracted from my **tools.xml** file.

I started off my **showspecifictool.php** file like this, however I'm not sure what exactly I should do in order to achieve what I want:

```
<?php
   $xml = new DOMDocument;
   $xml->load('tools.xml');
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   {
      //do something here
   }
    
}

?>
```

In the end I want my output to look something like this:

> Name: Facebook
>
> Type: . . .
>
> Web-based: . . .
>
> Free: . . .
>
> Description: . . .
>
> Url: . . .
>
> Subjects: . . .
>
> Creators: . . .
>
> Category: . . .
>
> Price: . . .

Comment: The user notes on the [domxpath documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) might help you figure out how to write an xpath query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show information about the selected Engineering Tools using xPath in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088508/how-to-show-information-about-the-selected-engineering-tools-using-xpath-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is how you should set up the main php file:

```
<form method="POST" action="show.php" align="center">
    <fieldset>
        <legend align="center">Choose a tool:</legend>

        <select id="tool" name="tool">
            <?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');
                foreach($xml as $tool) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $tool->name. "'>".$tool->name."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" add="choose">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Notice, that I have set the name for the select to "tool" and that in each option value is equal to tool name. If you have different tools with same name, use ID field there.

And here is how to setup the show php file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');

    foreach ($xml as $tool) {
        if ($tool->name == $_REQUEST["tool"]){
            foreach ($tool as $k => $v){
                echo $k, ": $v<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I have updated the xml to the following structure:

```
<tools>
    <tool type="..." web-based="..." free="...">
        <name>Facebook</name>
        <description>...</description>
        <url>...</url>
        <subjects>...</subjects>
        <creators>...</creators>
        <category>...</category>
        <price>...</price>
    </tool>
</tools>
```

The output:

```
name: Facebook
description: ...
url: ...
subjects: ...
creators: ...
category: ...
price: ...
```

---

Update using XPath:

This will find exact tool using xpath approach:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){
    $tool_name = $_REQUEST["tool"];

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');

    $tool = $xml->xpath("//tool/name[. = '$tool_name']/parent::*");

    foreach ($tool[0] as $k => $v){
        echo $k, ": $v<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply! And second of all, is there any way to achieve the same result by using XPath query in the show.php file?

Comment: This works perfectly by the way, but I want to know if there's an XPath solution for this. :)

Comment: Added proper xpath solution as well (it's better than in your original answer, as it finds the particular tool with the help of xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jancha's answer, I was able to alter it just a little bit and make it work with XPath the same way.

modified **show.php** file:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');
    $tools = $xml->xpath("//tool");

    foreach ($tools as $tool) {
        if ($tool->name == $_REQUEST["tool"]){
            foreach ($tool as $k => $v){
                echo $k, ": $v<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
  }
?>
```